# Python: Add row to list with two columns?

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

New to python so...

I have a list with two columns, like so:

```
>>>print langs
[{u'code': u'en', u'name': u'ENGLISH'}, {u'code': u'hy', u'name': u'ARMENIAN'}, ... {u'code': u'ms', u'name': u'MALAY'}]
```

I would like to add another row with:

code: xx and name: UNKNOWN

Tried with `langs.append` and so on, but can't get the hang of it.

Comment: This is actually a list of dictionaries

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's pretty easy:

```
>>> langs.append({u'code': u'xx', u'name': u'UNKNOWN'})
```

But I'd use `collections.namedtuple` for this kind of job(when columns are well-defined):

```
In [1]: from collections import namedtuple
In [2]: Lang = namedtuple("Lang", ("code", "name"))
In [3]: langs = []
In [4]: langs.append(Lang("xx", "unknown"))

In [5]: langs[0]
Out[5]: Lang(code='xx', name='unknown')

In [6]: langs[0].code
Out[6]: 'xx'

In [7]: langs[0].name
Out[7]: 'unknown'
```

Comment: Of course it was easy :-)
Thanks mate
I will look into namedtuple!

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it...

```
langs += [{u'code': u'xx', u'name': u'UNKNOWN'}]
```